# Wp Query custom search by meta query

Tags: meta-query

The post meta name of a post is "Klevis V. Miho". Now when searching for:

"Klevis Miho" => Nothing displays

Is it possible to show results with that search string?

Below is what I am up to now:

```
$args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key'     => 'name',
    'value'   => $name,
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
);
```

Comment: Is the title part of some kind of post meta or is it the actual post title?

Comment: It is a post meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way:

```
$name = explode(' ', $name);
foreach($name as $string) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'     => 'name',
        'value'   => $string,
        'compare' => 'LIKE' 
    );
}
```

Which works good, but I'm not sure if that's the best solution.

Comment: Please accept your own answer. This will get this question marked solved. :-)